# Простейший API с удаленным сайтом на php и js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, api

Пытаюсь сделать простейший API между одним сайтом и другим, попробовать реализовать самый простейший вариант, а именно просто отправить запрос к php странице сайта и получить обратно данные которые она выедет.

на сервере стоит такой php файл:

```
 $v['id'] ='11'; $v['nn']='22';
 echo json_encode($v);
```

просто генерирует тестовую строку в джейсоне

а вот так я пытаюсь отправить запрос на получение данных от этого файла

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://www.****.com/hyst/acore.php",
        type: "GET",

        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(resultData) {
            alert(resultData);

        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

но у меня к сожалению выскакивает ошибка, где я ошибся? уместно ли использовать тут аякс если домены у сайта с API и сайта который отправляет запрос разные? если не аякс то как лучше сделать?

Comment: если выскакивает ОШИБКА (сами знаете какая), то уже ничего не поможет.

Comment: Какая ошибка возникает?

Comment: @XelaNimed textStatus когда показывается alert ом выдает error но вот если посмотреть в консоли то там всё отлично запрос уходит и там виден ответ https://ibb.co/whdcfKQ со всеми нужными параметрами, так что ту дело в самом скрипте он наверно не правильный

Comment: А почему тип запроса HTML, а не JSON? Что показывает консоль в textStatus или resultData ?

Comment: Заголовок `header('Content-type: application/json');` на PHP сервере посылаете браузеру/клиенту?

Comment: @XelaNimed поставил, но к сожалению ничего не поменялось\

Comment: Вместо alert'а выведите ответ в консоль и приведите здесь ответ: console.log(arguments).

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался! В общем может кому потребуется решение похожего? в общем дело было в том что в php обработчике отсутствовала строка

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

в итоге мой обработчик (acore.php) стал выглядеть так

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
 header("Content-type: application/json; charset: utf-8");;
 $v['id'] ='11'; $v['nn']='22';
 echo json_encode($v);
```

ну, а запрос решил делать так:

```
  fetch('http://www.****.com/hyst/acore.php')
      .then(function(response) {
        //alert(response.headers.get('Content-Type')); // application/json; charset=utf-8
        //alert(response.status); // 200

        return response.json();
       })
      .then(function(data) {
        alert(data.id); // тут выходит наши данные записанные под id
      })
      .catch( alert );
```

хотя можно и вот так вызывать

```
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'http://www.****.com/hyst/acore.php', false);

    request.onload = function() { 
      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        alert(data.id);
      } else {
        alert('error');
      }
    };
  request.send();
```

Comment: Может имеет смысл ограничить сайтом (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.****.com`), а не разрешать (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`) всем выполнять запросы к Вашему API?

Comment: @XelaNimed да согласен, я просто в этом новичок) но у меня там другая проблема возникла теперь, когда тестирую через браузер - все соединение запрос\ответ происходит отлично, но когда монтирую его через cordova в apk файл и запускаю на телефоне, скрипт выдает error 404 и вот не могу понять - это получается уже в самом приложении надо выставлять что бы ему разрешалось посылать http запросы

Comment: На мой взгляд, это уже другой вопрос, но смотрите в сторону отладки Cordova на Visual Studio или другой IDE https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/run-your-app/run-app-android?view=toolsforcordova-2017

Answer (score 0):

Решение в создании ещё одного файла PHP - мост
JS обращается к PHP- мост а PHP - мост обращается к внешнему ресурсу по средством "include(resource_URL)", дальше он возвращает нужные вам данные...

Comment: да я думаю такое подошло бы но у меня то приложение которое вызывает к сожалению не может использовать php файлы это js приложение которое потом монтируется кордовой в apk формат\

Comment: попробуйте убрать :  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

Comment: к сожалению всё равно в textStatus приходит error( при том в консоле видно что ответ сайт дает! https://ibb.co/whdcfKQ